# Code quality issues: CPD: This extension contains duplicated code. in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We made a module & submitted in marketplace & they gave the main issue :-
Code quality issues: CPD: This extension contains duplicated code.

Here is one of them :-
File: Vendorname/module-name/Vendorname-module-name-2.0.0.0/Controller/Adminhtml/Myitems/MassDisable.php
Line: 11
File: magento/module-cms/magento-module-cms-102.0.0.0-RC21/Controller/Adminhtml/Page/MassDisable.php
Line: 11

Can anyone please suggest what to do in such case?

Comment: Add constructor same as base file and pass required argument in __parent::__construct();__ so your final code is like `parent::__construct($context, $filter, $collectionFactory)` then remove var/generation and flush cache

Comment: Hi Prince, Thank you for your quick help :) Now I did as you said but now this error coming :-

Total Errors Count: 1
Errors during compilation:
        Vendorname\Modulename\Controller\Rewrite\Adminhtml\Myitems\MassDisable
                Incompatible argument type: Required type: \Magento\Cms\Model\ResourceModel\Page\CollectionFactory. Actual type: \Vendorname\Modulename\Model\ResourceModel\Myitems\CollectionFactory; File:
/opt/lampp/htdocs/M2store/app/code/Vendorname/Modulename/Controller/Rewrite/Adminhtml/Myitems/MassDisable.php